handling asyn options in dropdown and auto complete inputs with form generator, Angular
I am using a form generator to logic in my application, I want to handle an asynchronous calls inn dropDown and autoComplete inputs based on some formControls value changes.
this is how I construct the dropDownInput in any component:
new DropdownInput({
                name: 'Agency Name',
                multiple: true,
                formControlName: 'agencyIds',
                classes: 'col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12',
                placeholder: 'Shams travel',
                asyncOptions: (pageSize, pageNo) => this.manageAgency.getAll({ status: 1 }, { pageSize, pageNo }).pipe(map((res) => res.payload)),
                optionLabel: 'name',
                optionValue: 'id',
                VirtualScroll: true,
                VirtualScrollObject: {
                    virtualScrollItemSize: 43,
                },
            }),

and here is how I handle the options in the DropDownInputComponent:
getOptions(): void {
    if (this.input.asyncOptions) {
        this.isLoading = true
        this.input.asyncOptions(this.pageSize, this.currentPage).subscribe((options) => {
            this.isLoading = false
            this.options = options
        })
        this.cdr.detectChanges()
    } else {
        if (!(this.input.options instanceof Array)) {
            ;(this.input.options as () => Observable<unknown[]>)().subscribe((options) => (this.options = options))
        } else {
            this.options = this.input.options
            this.cdr.detectChanges()
        }
    }
}

till now the logic works perfectly fine.
I want to add another logic to asyncOptions so that it accepts a string which is gonna be a formControlName so that I can subscribe to its changes in the DropDownInputComponent and update the options based on it.
I defined asyncOptions as follow:
    asyncOptions?: (size: number, page: number) => Observable<T[]> | ((formControlName: string) => Observable<T[]>)

and in some cases it's gonna be like this:
new DropdownInput({
                name: 'Agency Name',
                multiple: true,
                formControlName: 'agencyIds',
                classes: 'col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12',
                placeholder: 'Shams travel',
                asyncOptions: ('countryId') => this.manageAgency.getAll({ status: 1 }).pipe(map((res) => res.payload)),
                optionLabel: 'name',
                optionValue: 'id',
                VirtualScroll: true,
                VirtualScrollObject: {
                    virtualScrollItemSize: 43,
                },
            }),

I don't know how can I access the countryId argument in the DropDownInputComponent so that I can handle the logic.
